# Informatica Session Failing

Tags: ssrs-2008, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I created a mapping that pulls data from a flat file that shows me usage data for specific SSRS reports.  The file is overwritten each day with the previous days usage data.  My issue is, sometimes the report doesn't have any usage for that day and my ETL sends me a "Failed" email because there wasn't any data in the Source.  The job from running if there is no data in the source or to prevent it from failing.

--Thanks

Comment: "...is there a way to keep the job from running when there is no data in the source..."

Comment: Hi Johnson, its not the session is failing because there is no data in the source. Post your error message, will be helpful to provide you a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to solve this is to create a "Passthrough" mapping that only contains a flat file source, source qualifier, and a flat file target.

You would create a session that runs this mapping at the beginning of your workflow and have it read your flat file source.  The target can just be a dummy flat file that you keep overwriting.  Then you would have this condition in the link to your next session that would actually process the file:

```
$s_Passthrough.SrcSuccessRows > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways, you can do this.

You can provide an empty file to ETL job when there is no source data. To do this, use a pre-session command like `touch <filename>` in the Informatica workflow. This will create an empty file with the `<filename>` if it is not present. The workflow will run successfully with 0 rows.

If you have a script that triggers the Informatica job, then you can put a check there as well like this:

```
if [ -e <filename> ]
then
    pmcmd ...
fi
```

This will skip the job from executing.

Comment: Hi Samik, very good answer. Really appreciated. But the thing is, he has the source file without the data. That should work without issues. Hope they have a condition on e-mail task. And also touch command provides you the dummy file with no column name, which will fail while executing session

Comment: Hey Jim, I thought there was no source file, which was why the workflow was failing. Are you sure, it will fail if there are no column names in the file? I have to check that.

Comment: Yeah sure it will fail. Because during session execution, SQL override query will not provide any column name form the source. To keep on touch with informatica, just have a path - https://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/

Comment: You cannot have SQL overrides on file!

Comment: Am not mentioning a file. Override query will generate column names automatically while executing session, if there is no columns provided - session will fail

Comment: Hey guys, to clarify.  We receive a source file each morning with the previous days data.  The file is overwritten every day.  Most days the file has data in it, but other days like Monday when noone viewed the report on Sunday, it has no data. But there is always a source file.   "Error code 8361 error loading row to target table"  "SQL: Stmt: INSERT INTO TABLE A, VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Answer (score 0):

Have another session before the actual dataload. Read the file, use a FALSE filter and some dummy target. Link this one to the session you already have and set the following link condition:

```
$yourDummySessionName.SrcSuccessRows > 0
```